# python parallel browsers with different url

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I would like to run function of Python which open chrome browser in parallel with different `url` from `url_list` in Python.

I am running the example below, and it doesn't works.

I would like to run function of python which open chrome browser in parallel with different url from url_list in Python

I am expecting the 3 chrome browsers will be opened in parallel(3 url=3 web browsers)

```
import concurrent.futures

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url_list = \["https://www.example.com", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.openai.com"\]

class Test_concurrent:

    def open_browser_with_url(url):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get(url)
        yield driver
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.quit()
    
    
    def test_perform_actions(self):
        num_parallel_sessions = len(url_list)
    # Open browsers in parallel using ThreadPoolExecutor
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_parallel_sessions) as executor:
            executor.map(Test_concurrent().open_browser_with_url, url_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, parallelizing the opening of browsers with different URLs is quite straightforward using concurrent and Futures. Let's first look at the problem with your code: the `executor.map` method requires that you pass the function object to be executed, not the result of calling the function. Thus, in your code, calling `Test_concurrent().open_browser_with_url` doesn't make sense. Instead, you should pass the function itself to `map`, and let `map` call `open_browser_with_url` for each URL in the list.
Let's revise the `executor.map` statement to properly invoke `open_browser_with_url` for each URL in `url_list`:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_parallel_sessions) as executor:
    executor.map(Test_concurrent.open_browser_with_url, url_list)
```

Now when you execute the code, the ThreadPoolExecutor will spawn `num_parallel_sessions` threads to simultaneously call `open_browser_with_url`.

The `open_browser_with_url` function will now be called for each URL in `url_list`, in their own threads. Because the threads will execute in parallel, as soon as each thread completes its task (i.e. finishes navigating to the URL), you may see a number of Chrome browser windows opening up in quick succession. However, this will depend on the speed of the computer and the quality of the network connection. If all goes well, you should see three separate browsers with different URL simultaneously on your computer screen, each corresponding to one URL from `url_list`.